# How to create a third column called "Weight" based on value of other column? When the column value is NA, a 0 weight would be assigned

Tags: r, dplyr, calculated-columns

I have 4 columns in a data frame, and based on the 2 columns, the 5th column of weights needs to be created. When the column value is NA, a 0 weight would be assigned.

Suppose I have this data frame in R called exp.

```
  from  to tel post
1  S01 S02 123  ABC
2  S02 S03 456 <NA>
3  S04 S05  NA  XYZ
```

I need to create the following weight column. 
Where weight = 10 * (tel) + 1* (post)

if the value is NA, then its zero

```
  from  to tel post weight
1  S01 S02 123  ABC  11
2  S02 S03 456 <NA>  10
3  S04 S05  NA  XYZ  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
with(df, (10 * !is.na(tel)) + (1 * !is.na(post)))

[1] 11 10  1
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "  from  to tel post
1  S01 S02 123  ABC
2  S02 S03 456 <NA>
3  S04 S05  NA  XYZ",
                 header = TRUE,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 na.strings = c("NA", "<NA>"))
```